# Ornamental grape vine

Tags: pests

I have something eating my ornamental grape vine new growth. Can you suggest something please? The vine is about 5 years old and perfectly healthy otherwise.  I haven’t tried anything as yet.

Comment: Do you have  a picture of the leaves?, so we can see if it is caterpillars or other things.

Comment: Eating leaves or grapes? A photo would be nice, and maybe your location